# Unable to edit an xml file

Tags: python-3.x, string, lxml, xml.etree

I have a xml file with **b**'+ **xml_content** +**'** in the file and
I want to delete the "b'" and "'" from starting and ending of the file so that I can parse the xml content but when I am unable to edit that file. Any suggestions. I am already writing to edit that file opening it and reading it as s**strong text**tring but unable to write edited part.

Comment: b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<!DOCTYPE register_monolith SYSTEM "register_monolith.dtd">\nb\'<register_monolith timestamp="None"><registers/><libraries count="0"/></register_monolith>\''
example of xml file

Comment: Do you really have an *XML file* whose content looks like that? The `b` prefix normally indicates that you are dealing with a a `bytes` object. Please show us your code.